# Variables losing data between activities and I don't know why?

Tags: java, android

I am currently creating an android app that scans a network and outputs results in a ListView but I am trying to make it to where I tap on the network and it saves the data in a database then sends you to a page to show you what you selected but when I click an item it substrings the values correctly and displays work fine on the main activity but when I try to use the variables on my display page activity there values are set null.

Here is the main activity in the click listener:

```
networklist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String grabItemInfo = wifis[position];

            Network_Info info1 = new Network_Info();

            info1.setMainBSSID( grabItemInfo.substring(grabItemInfo.indexOf('#') +1, grabItemInfo.lastIndexOf('#')));
            info1.setMainSSID( grabItemInfo.substring(0,(grabItemInfo.indexOf('#'))));
            info1.setMainCAP( grabItemInfo.substring(grabItemInfo.lastIndexOf('#')+1, grabItemInfo.length()));


            Toast toastTest = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info1.getMainSSID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Toast toastTest2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info1.getMainBSSID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Toast toastTest3 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info1.getMainCAP(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toastTest.show();
            toastTest2.show();
            toastTest3.show();

            ContentValues dbv = new ContentValues();

            dbv.put("SSID", info1.getMainSSID());
            dbv.put("BSSID", info1.getMainBSSID());
            dbv.put("CAPABILITIES", info1.getMainCAP());




            netDataBase.insert("netDataTable", "NULL", dbv);


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Attack_Page.class);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
```

Here is my display page:

```
public class Attack_Page extends Network_List {


protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedIS){

    super.onCreate(SavedIS);
    setContentView(R.layout.attack_page);


    TextView SSIDview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SSIDView);
    TextView BSSIDview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BSSIDView);
    TextView CAPview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CAPView);
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //String MainSSIDP = intent.getStringExtra(getMainSSID());

    Network_Info info1 = new Network_Info();

    Toast testToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  info1.getMainSSID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    testToast.show();

    //Cursor IDselect = netDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT SSID FROM netDataTable WHERE SSID = "+getMainSSID()+"", wifis);

    //SSIDview.setText(IDselect.toString());


    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent bintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Network_List.class);
            startActivity(bintent);

        }


    });

}
```

}

Here is my setters and getters class:

```
public class Network_Info {
   private String mainCAP;
   private String mainSSID;
   private String mainBSSID;

public void setMainSSID(String newMainSSID){

    mainSSID = newMainSSID;

}

public void setMainBSSID(String newMainBSSID){

    mainBSSID = newMainBSSID;

}

public void setMainCAP(String newMainCAP){

    mainCAP = newMainCAP;

}

public String getMainSSID(){

    return mainSSID;

}
public String getMainBSSID(){

    return mainBSSID;

}
public String getMainCAP(){

    return mainCAP;

}
```

}

Comment: On your diplay page you're just instantiating Network_info and not actually reading it from the database

Comment: Unrelated, but `netDataBase.insert("netDataTable", "NULL", dbv);` should have `null` as the second param, not literally the string `"NULL"`

Comment: Also, do you really need the database? You should be able to pass data directly in the Intent

Comment: Sorry about the database, I didn't want to include a database in the first place but I am forced to fill a requirement for a competition. For now the database is commented out in the display page and should be disregarded as I am getting rid of it and making a separate page that shows all the saved information. The main problem I am having is that when i try to use a toast to show the value of the variable in my display page it returns blank.

Comment: Right, because you made a `new Network_Info()`, and `getMainSSID()` returns `null` because it is un-initialized in your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you have to pass the variable with the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Attack_Page.class);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SSID", info1.getMainSSID());
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_BSSID", info1.getMainBSSID());
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_CAP", info1.getMainCAP());
            startActivity(intent);
```

Then use the key that you set in putExtra()

```
 String MainSSIDP = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_SSID");
```

Thanks for the help though!